# Is there something like "ON DELETE NULL"?

Tags: android, sqlite, cascading-deletes

I have two tables:

```
create table notes (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    title text not null,
    body text not null,
    category text,
    foreign key(category) references categories(title) on delete null);

create table categories (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    title text unique not null);
```

I'm wondering if there's something like `ON DELETE CASCADE` but instead of deleting the content, changing it to `NULL`

Obviously `ON DELETE NULL` does not work.

EDIT: I achieved this by using a trigger:

```
"create trigger trg_delete before delete " +
                "on categories " +
                "begin " +
                "update notes set category = null where category = old.title; " +
                "end";
```

Comment: yes you can use ON DELETE SET NULL  .http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @yasiriqbal776 it compiles and gives no error, but doesn't do anything :/

Comment: this does not work because you have to set the category column to null otherwise as by foreign key rule it cannot be null

Comment: @yasiriqbal776 I don't get this, what do I have to set to null from category? Can you provide an example? Note that I'm not much into databases

Comment: create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "title text not null, body text not null, category text default null," +
                " foreign key(category) references categories(title) on delete set default);     try this query i hope problem will be solved :)

Comment: @yasiriqbal776 nope, it keeps doing nothing -.-

Maybe it's a problem when I create a "note"? Do I have to do anything special when adding a category to a "note"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102503/discussion-between-dari1495-and-yasiriqbal776).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102558/discussion-between-yasiriqbal776-and-dari1495).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use triggers to achieve what you are intended 
Create a Before delete trigger on your table and in that trigger just update the forien key to null

```
//example
CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete BEFORE Delete 
ON categories 
BEGIN
update  notes set categories=null  where categories = old._id;
END
```

hear is a [link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to know more about triggers

Comment: Is there a way to do this on Android?

Comment: yes you can do this in android as well use the same query to do so after you create the tables

Comment: you can also use the Sqlite manager and do it there try it your self

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, that action is not spelled ON DELETE NULL but [ON DELETE SET NULL](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions):

```
create table notes (
    [...],
    foreign key(category) references categories(title) on delete set null);
```